# vertex ai dataset import imageGcsUri with generation number

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dataset, google-cloud-vertex-ai

When using Vertex AI, I'm trying to import a specific version of my images into my dataset using the generation number of that version.
So instead of using having a line in my CSV like this:

```
gs://MYBUCKET/clouds/cumulonimbus/3.jpg,cumulonimbus
```

I want to specify the generation number:

```
gs://MYBUCKET/clouds/cumulonimbus/3.jpg#1786754391100710,cumulonimbus
```

When I do that, I'm getting an error during import: "Error: Permission denied on gs://MYBUCKET/clouds/cumulonimbus/3.jpg#1786754391100710 (or it may not exist)."

I'm not sure if there's a way to do that.

Thank you.

Comment: Does the image with generation number appears automatically in gcs once created?

Answer (score 0):

Since `"imageGcsUri": "gs://bucket/filename.ext"` is the **Cloud Storage URI**, you are expected to use the same format. One workaround is to you rename the specific image with the **generation number** and make that the file extension was put accordingly.
E.g.

```
gs://MYBUCKET/clouds/cumulonimbus/1786754391100710.jpg,cumulonimbus
```

Also, make sure that you have the **required permissions** in order to use this service.